# create a Docker Swarm v1.12.3 service and mount a NFS volume

Tags: nfs, docker-swarm

I'm unable to get a NFS volume mounted for a Docker Swarm, and the lack of proper official documentation regarding the --mount syntax (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/) doesnt help.

I have tried basically this command line to create a simple nginx service with a /kkk directory mounted to an NFS volume:

docker service create --mount type=volume,src=vol_name,volume-driver=local,dst=/kkk,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=192.168.1.1:/your/nfs/path --name test nginx

The command line is accepted and the service is scheduled by Swarm, but the container never reaches "running" state and swarm tries to start a new instance every few seconds. I set the daemon to debug but no error regarding the volume shows...

Which is the right syntax to create a service with a NFS volume?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I found an article here that shows how to mount nfs share (and that works for me): http://collabnix.com/docker-1-12-swarm-mode-persistent-storage-using-nfs/

```
sudo docker service create \
--mount type=volume,volume-opt=o=addr=192.168.x.x,volume-opt=device=:/data/nfs,volume-opt=type=nfs,source=vol_collab,target=/mount \
--replicas 3 --name testnfs \
alpine /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo 'OK'; sleep 2; done"
```

---

**Update:**
In case you want to use it with docker-compose you can do it the following:

```
version: '3'

services:

  alpine:
    image: alpine
    volumes:
      - vol_collab:/mount
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
    command: /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo 'OK'; sleep 2; done"


volumes:
  vol_collab:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=192.168.xx.xx
      device: ":/data/nfs"
```

and then run it with

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also this in docker compose to create nfs volume

```
  data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: addr=<nfs-Host-domain-name>,rw,sync,nfsvers=4.1
      device: ":<path to directory in nfs server>"
```